# How to get data from array in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

In the picture below data is in array properties but I want to get the selected data into a textfield. How to do that?

[image: Picture]

Comment: What did you tried? Please post sample code you tried?

Comment: i have 3 fields to get the data by selecting the record from table which is shown in above pic, but data is in array, dont know how to fetch it into my fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [complex syntax](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/25ab54b0113c4914999c43d07d3b71fe.html) as follows:

```
oTxt = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
    value: {
        parts: [
            {path: "/yourArray[index]/relevantAttribute"},
            {path: "/yourArray[index]/relevantAttribute"},
            ...
        ]
    }
});
```

Additional information can be found [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/a2fe8e763014477e87990ff50657a0d0.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can access the array using below:

aTokens[i].mProperties.value.OrderType